# OpenGL attribute-less fullscreen quad

Tags: opengl

i was trying to render a fullscreen quad using a single triangle directly defined in the vertex shader using

```
out vec2 tex_coord;

const vec2 pos_data[3] = vec2[] (
    vec2(-1.0, -1.0),
    vec2( 3.0, -1.0),
    vec2(-1.0,  3.0)
);

const vec2 tex_data[3] = vec2[] (
    vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    vec2(2.0, 0.0),
    vec2(0.0, 2.0)
);

void main() {
    tex_coord = tex_data[ gl_VertexID ];
    gl_Position = vec4( pos_data[ gl_VertexID ], 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

Everything works fine until i switch to a context with core profile.
Error 1282 occurs and shuts down my program.
The reason is that i dont have a VerteArrayObject bound for rendering.
Since i dont need it filled with data, i just bind a dummy one and everything works again.

Is there a way to get around this dummy object and still follow the specification ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to get around this dummy object and still follow the specification ?

No. Having a non-zero VAO bound is an absolute requirement for every `glDraw*` call, as per the spec.

**UPDATE**:

In the [current OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf), you will find the following language in section 10.4 "Drawing Commands Using Vertex Arrays":

> The command
>
> ```
>  void DrawArraysOneInstance( enum mode, int first, sizei count, int instance, uint baseinstance );
> ```
>
> does not exist in the GL,
>   but is used to describe functionality in the rest of this section.
>
> [...]
>
> **Errors**
>
> [...]
>
> An `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated if no vertex array object is bound (see section 10.3.1)

All other `glDraw*` commands are explained in terms of this hypothetical command, so all properties described there will be inheritet by all other draw commands, including the errors that may be generated.

**Other alternatives**

Since you only seem to want to draw a fullscreen quad, there are some potential alternatives for certain special cases.

If you only want to draw some texture, without applying any special effects in the shader, you could pontially attach that texture to a color attachment of an FBO, and use it a s a source for `glBlitFramebuffer`, so that you basically just blit this texture to the screen, without altering any draw-related state at all.

There is also the NV-specific extenstion [GL_NV_draw_texture](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/draw_texture.txt), which goes into the same direction. Quoting from the "Overview" section of said extension (my emphasis):

> This extension provides a new function,`DrawTextureNV()`, allowing  applications to draw an screen-aligned rectangle displaying some or all of the contents of a two-dimensional or rectangle texture. [...]
>
> No shaders are used by `DrawTextureNV`; the results of the > texture lookup are used in lieu of a fragment shader
>   output. [...]
>
> While this functionality can be obtained in unextended OpenGL by drawing a
>   rectangle and using a fragment shader to do a texture lookup,
>   `DrawTextureNV()` is likely to have better power efficiency on
>   implementations supporting this extension.  **Additionally, use of this
>    extension frees the application developer from having to set up
>   specialized shaders, transformation matrices, vertex attributes, and
>   various other state in order to render the rectangle.**

However, both of the methods I discussed here only address the case where you basically want to blit some texture to the screen, with filtering, but without any custom per-fragment operations.

If you want to have custom per-fragment processing, you either have to go through the render pipeline using some `glDraw*()` command (and needing a VAO), or you could also use a compute shader writing into a 2D texture via `image_load_store` functionality. I doubt that it would be worth it, in the general case, but that will of course depend on the specifics of your actual use case.

Comment: thanks, that was also what i assumed to be the case. can you help me finding that in the specification or do you know under which section i have to search to get more insight into this?

Comment: do i have to feed any data to the VAO or is a complete blank one fine in the end?

Comment: A complete blank one will do just fine.

Comment: what is the reason then? this descision sounds quite arbitrary if i dont need at least the amount of data/vertices in a buffer i want to feed through the pipeline, even if i actually don't use them

Comment: @JKreiser: I updated my answer, and also discussed some potential alternatives. The reason is that the render pipeline traditionally uses inputs, and there might be fixed-function vertex fetch stage in hardware (nvidia is said to use that, so that it can better schedule the shader invocations, and especially not start them before the data is ready), so the GPU needs to know what to fetch. The question is what happens if you don't use the values for which the vertex attribute arrays are enbaled, and that is totally implementation-specific, and beyond the spec.

Comment: @JKreiser: so the question might be: what happens if you not specifically use that particular "empty" VAO. Case 1: you use no other VAOs in your app. Then, just binding an empty VAO right at the start wouldn't be a big deal. Case 2: you have some other VAOs. So what would happen if you just keep just the last one in use bound for the attrib-less draw. As long as anny enabled attrib array pointer points to valid memory for the first three elements, it must not crash. But will it potentially do some unnecessary fetches? That's up to the implementation...

Comment: thanks for that very detailed answer, did not expect that! i'm actually using my fullscreen quad for both, post-processing and the final display. i've read that `glBlitFramebuffer` is slower, but have to investigate this. i'll continue reading and maybe getting enlighten :D

Comment: @JKreiser: there is no reason for `glBlitFramebuffer` being slower in general.